# DAX - Calculation based on several related tables' filtering result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Hi I tried hard to calculate the result but it was still wrong, hope anyone could give advice. Many thanks in advance.

**Desired Result:** To have a calculated column in [Product table] displaying if this product has inventory based on filters in both [Warehouse table] and [Inventory table].

**Filter Logic:**

1. Based on [Inventory table], to see if there is online products' inventory for this SKU in "region" BJ

   - (Region information is coming from [Warehouse table]) &( Online information is coming from [Product table]
2. Based on result of the first step, to display SKUs in the [Product table] that **DON'T** appear in the previous filtering result

**My code:**

```
=
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Inventory' ),
        FILTER (
            'Inventory',
            'Product'[IfOnline] = "Online " && RELATED ( 'Warehouse'[Region] ) = "BJ"
        )
    )
        > 0,
    "BJ has inventory",
    "BJ has no inventory"
)
```

The table relationship is listed as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[column] =
IF (
[IfOnline] = "Online"
    && CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS('Inventory'),
        Warehouse[Region] = "BJ"
    )
        > 0,
"BJ has inventory",
"BJ has no inventory"
)
```

It would be even beter to sum the Qty column in stead of counting the rows. In case the Qty is 0.

```
[column] =
IF (
[IfOnline] = "Online"
    && CALCULATE (
        SUM('Inventory'[Qty]),
        Warehouse[Region] = "BJ"
    )
        > 0,
"BJ has inventory",
"BJ has no inventory"
)
```